# Why does my heroku app crash without showing any error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, heroku, nestjs

There is no error in logs, and around 50 seconds after it says `Nest application successfully started`, it says: `State changed from starting to crashed`. The last log before the crash is a console log which says the port number.
[Heroku logs after successful building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRXhq.png)

Does anybody know how to fix this? or at least where to see a more detailed error log?

Comment: You'll need to show the full logs between start and crash. There's not enough information here to determine the issue. To see more logs, in your application dashboard click "More" in the upper right hand corner, then click "View Logs". This should show you the logs for the running app. Usually it's helpful to also restart the application while on the "View Logs" page so you can get a full capture of what's happening.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, and my logs are also completely empty. I get a log message saying the server is up, and then I get State changed from starting to crashed after a short while. Logs are the same when using heroku logs --tail and when looking in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had exactly the same problem. My server would crash shortly after the deploy without any log messages.

For me the problem was that my server was listing to `http://127.0.0.1:{PORT}`. When I changed the server to listen to `http://0.0.0.0:PORT` my issue was solved.

I am assuming that the container Heroku uses under the hood does not default to exposing mapped ports to localhost. I am using Fastify and found the solution here: https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aea4100062353cf4da1cfcb4fe8167ac0092117c/docs/Server.md#listen

Hope this helps!